# Why is steam wrong in its game count?

Tags: steam

[Referring to this image,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbNGo.png) steam says I have 11 games in total and 10 installed. However, if you count them (Yes, I have counted them a million times.), you get 12 total and 11 installed.

What's wrong? Also, for a fact: I haven't got the badge for 10 games owned, but I have it for 5 games owned.

Comment: Try uninstalling the free trial, see if that affects either number.

Comment: @deworde It affects both numbers.

Comment: Do all of your games work when played?  Maybe one of them was improperly installed.

Comment: Note that sometimes DLC will cause discrepancies in game counting in some areas of Steam community as well.

Comment: We all know Valve cannot accurately count past 2. What did you expect!

Comment: @MiloPrice I don't have any DLC.

Answer (score 6):

Dota 2 Test is not counted in the first case.  Test and Beta versions of games don't count as games, so there is 12 entries, only 11 games.

Free-to-play games/free trials are not counted in the second.

Comment: Um, by first case, you mean, total games, and second, is installed games? Cause if by second, you mean the badge, I don't have 5 paid games. (But I have the badge), if you even understand.

Comment: The only paid game on the list is Awesomenauts as far as I know..

Comment: Also, still doesn't explain the wrong count. It's still 12 total and 11 installed (11 cause Dota 2 Test isn't included), but steam says, it's one less.

Comment: This can not be correct, because Dota2 test is the only one that is not installed... which is something he counts

Comment: Alright, then why does my installed say 10? I have 11 installed.

Answer (score 0):

Like all above there are f2p games you must have downloaded another f2p game and uninstalled it. If you download a f2p game your account will count it in the games that you own even if you uninstall it. I have 280ish games but my account also counts some (not all) f2p games just the ones i have downloaded and tryed so it makes my game count go into the 300's.

Comment: But his game count is lower than the number of games on his list, not higher.  Your explaination would only explain things if his game count were higher than the number of games on his list.

Comment: oh im missread the question @.@ its too early for thinking

Comment: It's okay.  We all make mistakes.